# Returning early from a function

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm having a mental block, can someone remind me what the correct term for returning early from a function is, i.e.

```
private MyObject DoSomeStuff(string myValue)
{
    //What is this called?!?!?
    if(myValue == string.Empty)
        return null;

    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.Value = myValue;
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's called a guard clause.

Comment: reference [Replace Nested Conditionals with Guard Clauses](http://books.google.com/books?id=1MsETFPD3I0C&lpg=PP1&dq=refactoring&hl=en&pg=PA250#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  It turns out I hadn't forgot the term, I didn't know it in the first place. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would potentially call this an Interrupt.  Or, simply, and Early Return.  Break might work, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a "precondition test".